# How to deal with IOException

Tags: java, exception

So I have the following method that throws an IOException:

```
public static void saveObjectToTextFile(String string,
                                        String textFileName) throws     
IOException {
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(textFileName)));
        bw.write(string);
    } finally {
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that whenever I write another method that calls this above function I end up having to write `throws IOException` in the method header like the following:

```
void anotherMethod() throws IOException {
    FileInputOutput.saveObjectToTextFile(JSONobject,
                finalPathAndFile);
}
```

What can I do to not write `throws IOException` for `anotherMethod()`?

Comment: Well you'd have to catch the exception. But what do you want to *do* when an exception occurs? Can you actually handle it and keep going?

Comment: Put a try/catch clause in the other method. Or, use a different system in the first method, thus, eliminating the need to throw anything.

Comment: What about writing a catch block!?

Comment: The point of the `throws` keyword is to let the block of code that calls the method know the exception has not been handled. I don't understand why you have the `throws` keyword on `saveObjectToTextFile()` when the exception has been appropriately (sort of) handled in that method.

Answer (score 2):

How you implement this will depend on what it means when you get an exception at that point.  Is there something that can be done by *this* block of code?  If so, you deal with it here and continue

```
public static void saveObjectToTextFile(String string,
                                        String textFileName){ // no throws

    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(textFileName)))) { // use try-with-resources
        bw.write(string);
    } catch(IOException e){
         // deal with the exception
    } // no close necessary for try-with-resources
}
```

If there isn't anything *this* block of code can do with the exception, wrap it in some subclass of `RuntimeException`

```
public static void saveObjectToTextFile(String string,
                                        String textFileName){ // no throws

    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(textFileName)))) { // use try-with-resources
        bw.write(string);
    } catch(IOException e){
         throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot write the string to " + textFileName,e);
    } // no close necessary for try-with-resources
}
```

Just to be clear:  "Dealing with it" typically means doing something constructive ,**other than logging**,  that would put the application in an acceptable state.  If the application expects this method to successfully write the string to the file, the latter implementation should be your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to catch your *IOException*:

```
public static void saveObjectToTextFile(String string,
                                    String textFileName)
{
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(textFileName)));
        bw.write(string);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //Handle the Exception
    } finally {
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

The close Method **doesn't** throw any Exception at all. The finally-block is meant to close or reset instances of variables or objects.

Comment: Close, don't nullify. The garbage collector is notoriously bad at handling any resources other than memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to throw the exception further, you have to catch it in the method, which would work like the following:

```
void anotherMethod() {
   try {
        FileInputOutput.saveObjectToTextFile(JSONobject,
            finalPathAndFile);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        // do something to handle the failure
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite you method `saveObjectToTextFile` as following, in such way you will catch an exception in the method itself and it won't propagate further.

```
public static void saveObjectToTextFile(String string,
                                        String textFileName) throws     
IOException {
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(textFileName)));
        bw.write(string);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       //do whatever you need to do with an exception for example to print it
       e.printStackTrace(); //print an exception to console
    }finally {
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();// don't leave exception untreated, you always should do something with exception, write it to log, etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Also take a look at this tutorial: [What is a exception?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

Comment: Having a `try-catch` in a `finally` block is pretty ugly. If a check of the `bw` instance is necessary, why not check if it's null?

Comment: `BufferedWriter.close()` can throw an exception http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close() , you can't avoid `try-catch` block here. You can write all this in a single `try--catch` block of course, but it will be more ugly. Better solution is to write external Class with static method to close resources. It should take care if an exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The `throws` keyword is kind of like a warning label on a product you could buy. It says that there's a chance that an exception (of the given type) could be thrown by the method. Moreover, if that type of exception does occur, the method isn't going to fix it - it will pass the exception up to the calling method, where you have to handle it.

The standard framework for actually *handling* exceptions (instead of just putting `throws` everywhere) is a `try...catch` block.

```
try {
    //Lines of code that may result in an IOException
} catch(IOException e) {
    //Lines of code that handle the thrown IOException e
} finally {
    //Lines of code that are run after the try...catch, regardless of what exceptions occurred.
}
```

If your try..catch block correctly handles the potential exception, then you won't need the `throws` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't catch you `IOException`. You use only the `try` block. If you catch the exception then calling method don't need to throw the `IOException`.

```
public static void saveObjectToTextFile(String string, String textFileName){

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(textFileName)));
        bw.write(string);
    } catch(IOException e) {

    } finally {
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

While catching exception using catch block it is a good practice to be more specific. That's why try I am catching `IOException` instead of `Exception`.